# How to take input through GPIO 12 p9_20 namely i2c2_SDA on debian beaglebone black using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, beagleboneblack, gpio, i2c

I am working on a project that requires me to communicate between my beaglebone black and the ds1307 ic. However I am unable to get any response. I think if you could only show me how to to get value as 1 with direction as in, my solution will work. So far, we have been using GPIO 12 and 13 for SDA and SCL. Despite manipulating the pinmux config and setting up the config for SDA to both 33 and B3(receiver enabled, pulled up, input and mode3). Here is the code I have been using.
[i2c.sh](https://gist.github.com/thenaughtychild/7e62068d78ac9031696c785112eaa082)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I scanned through you code briefly, Can you please tell us more about your debugging results. Do you see data been transmitting. Have your verified the wiring.  Little bit more details might be helpful